# Is it worth buying an iPad if I have an Android smartphone and Windows computer?

Tags: pc, tablet, apple

I am seriously considering buying a 9.7 iPad, but I have an Android phone and I am not sure about the compatibility between these 2. Is the hotspot functionality from my Android device going to work with the iPad? Is it going to be easy to connect to my Linux & Windows PC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues with hotspots. As for Linux/windows connectivity it depends what do you wish to do with your device. If you only wish to transfer songs/videos/pics then it will be fine with Windows through iTunes since Apple has a version for Windows. With Linux it gets a bit tricky. There isn't a version of iTunes that Linux supports natively, but you can get it running with WINE. In my personal experience (I use iPhone+iPad with Windows PC) it took quite some time to get used to iTunes, but once you do it works great.